# 1.0 sites are not listed in Stack Exchange 2.0

Tags: discussion, stack-exchange

Why are all the friend sites of [Stack Exchange 2.0](https://stackexchange.com/) not listed in the [Stack Exchange site directory page](https://stackexchange.com/sites) (Stack Exchange 1.0 sites)? I [found some sites using Google Search](http://www.google.co.in/search?q=site:stackexchange.com). Some sites are listed below:

> 1. [Austrian Economics Questions and Answers](http://mises.stackexchange.com/1.)
> 2. [Kiln Knowledge Exchange - Questions and Answers about
>    distributed version control and code
>    reviews](http://kiln.stackexchange.com/)
> 3. [A question and answer site for bioinformatics](http://biostar.stackexchange.com/)
> 4. [SQL Anywhere](http://sqla.stackexchange.com/)
> 5. [OpenLSL Exchange - Open-Source Portal for Second Life Scripters](http://openlsl.stackexchange.com/)
> 6. [FogBugz Knowledge Exchange](http://fogbugz.stackexchange.com/)
> 7. [EveryDNS.com Community](http://everydnscommunity.stackexchange.com/)
> 8. [Automotive Q&A on StackExchange](http://autos.stackexchange.com/)
> 9. [Answers On Fitness - get answers to questions about fitness, exercise
>    and nutration](http://answersonfitness.stackexchange.com/)
> 10. [Electronics Exchange](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/)
>
> etc. etc. etc......

Answer (score 2, accepted):

These are SE 1.0 sites. The Site Directory only contains the Trilogy sites (SO/SF/SU/MSO/StackApps) and all public SE 2.0 sites.

Comment: What is "Trilogy site"? and what is the difference between "SE 1.0" and "SE 2.0"?

Comment: @chanchal Trilogy is SOFU (Stack Overflow, Server Fault and Super User)

Comment: @HoLyVieR: and what is the difference between "SE 1.0" and "SE 2.0"?

Comment: @chan: SE 1.0 are StackOverflow-like sites created before the launch of Area 51. SE 2.0 are those created via Area 51. See http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/04/changes-to-stack-exchange/.