# Why don't all Stack Exchange sites show up in the list of 'all sites'?

Tags: discussion, stack-exchange

Specifically, I've been participating in [AskAboutProjects](http://www.askaboutprojects.com) a bit.  What is the difference between the 'Stack Exchange' pull down on these sites and the list  at http://www.stackexchangesites.com/ ?  Why does AskAboutProjects appear to be listed in only a few listings of SE sites?  Are there criteria that must be met before a site will appear in the StackExchange pull down?

I found [this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/61347/sites-are-not-listed-in-stackexchange), but I don't know enough about the design of the various SE sites to know whether it applies to my question.  What's a 1.0 or 2.0 site?  Does it even apply to what I'm talking about here?

Comment: Related question: [List of Stack Exchange subdomains that are not mentioned in “All Sites”](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/299365/295232).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The Gen-U-Wine™ Stack Exchange pull down only lists sites which were created through [Area 51](http://area51.stackexchange.com/?tab=progress). They are members of the (SE 2.0) Stack Exchange Network.

The other sites (not included in the listing) are privately-owned from back when users created their own Q&A sites hosted as a subscription service. They are not part of the Stack Exchange Network and, therefore, not listed in the drop down.

Comment: Interesting.  Is there a process for a privately owned site to migrate to the stack exchange network, or are these sites doomed to become stack exchange orphans?

Comment: The process is that we try to work with sites that have created successful communities to migrate them into Stack Exchange: http://basicallymoney.com, http://answers.onstartups.com, http://chiphacker.com. Proposing a site in Area 51 is another option. Otherwise, they have to make arrangements to host their data using other software.