# List of Stack Exchange subdomains that are not mentioned in "All Sites"

Tags: discussion, subdomains

I wanted a list of sub-domains of Stack Exchange that are not mentioned over here https://stackexchange.com/sites

Some of the sub-domains I found which were not mentioned are

- [Stack Exchange Chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com)
- [Stack Exchange Data Explorer](https://data.stackexchange.com)

Are there any other which are not mentioned?

---

Mentions by [Shadow Wizard](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/152859/shadow-wizard), [iBug](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/350567/ibug), [Glorfindel](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/295232/glorfindel)

- [Stack Exchange Development site](http://dev.stackexchange.com)
- [Stack Overflow Blog](https://stackoverflow.blog/)
- [StackPromos](https://stackpromos.com/)
- [Stack Overflow Business](https://www.stackoverflowbusiness.com/)
- [Stack Overflow Insights](https://insights.stackoverflow.com/)

---

Other mentions below which are not mentioned in "All Sites" but are mentioned in the drop down menu on the top left of the Stack Exchange website

- [Area 51](https://area51.stackexchange.com/)
- [CS50](https://cs50.stackexchange.com/)
- [StackApps](https://stackapps.com/)

**Any other website that's left out ?**

Comment: @ShadowWizard urrm, why is the list [here](https://dev.stackexchange.com/sites) different from the one [here](https://stackexchange.com/sites)?

Comment: @ItamarG3 different database probably, it doesn't work with the production database but with their dev database.

Comment: @ShadowWizard SO isn't on that db XD. probably due to the high traffic

Comment: Just a notice. CS50 isn't available from top-left dropdown. Only A51 and SA do.

Comment: Area 51 and StackApps are mentioned on All Sites.  How do I access this drop down menu?

Answer (score 12):

*All* sites that are not actual Q/A sites are not listed.

- [SE Chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com)
- [SE Data Explorer](https://data.stackexchange.com) - Often referred to as [SEDE](/search?q=SEDE)
- [SE Dev Test site](https://dev.stackexchange.com)
- [SE **OpenID**](https://openid.stackexchange.com)
- A few redirector sites (some of which changed names/domains in the past)

  - [Ask Ubuntu](https://ubuntu.stackexchange.com) (You can refer to AU with `[ubuntu.se]` as a quick shorthand link in comments)
  - [MathOverflow](https://mathoverflow.stackexchange.com)
  - [Nothing to Install (later Web Applications)](http://nothingtoinstall.com/)
  - [Mi Yodeya](http://mi.yodeya.com)
  - [Basically Money (later Personal Finance & Money)](http://basicallymoney.com/)
  - [Fantasy (later Science Fiction & Fantasy)](https://fantasy.stackexchange.com)
  - [Health (later Medical Sciences)](https://health.stackexchange.com)
- [Web Socket](https://qa.socket.stackexchange.com), the socket that powers [the realtime page](https://stackexchange.com/questions?tab=realtime)

Strictly speaking, [Area 51](https://area51.stackexchange.com) is not *in* the list, but it's easily known and accessible (it's in the top-left dropdown menu of all sites, though).

#### Other (sub)domains of Stack Overflow:

- [SO Chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com)
- [Stack Overflow Blog](https://stackoverflow.blog)
- [SO Blog Alternative](https://blog.stackoverflow.com), redirects to above
- [Stack Overflow "Facebook" tag](http://facebook.stackoverflow.com) - Redirects to SO with the [facebook](/questions/tagged/facebook) tag (previously, **a truckload** of facebook-related tags)
- [Stack Overflow Jobs](https://jobs.stackoverflow.com) - Discontinued as of April, 2022 (previously redirected to SO Talent)
- [Stack Overflow Careers](https://careers.stackoverflow.com) - Discontinued as of April, 2022 (previously redirected to SO Talent)
- [Stack Overflow Talent](https://talent.stackoverflow.com) - ↑↑↑
- [RADS](https://rads.stackoverflow.com) - Used to be a dedicated redirection site. Closed now (redirects to SO)
- [SO Developer Console](https://dev.stackoverflow.com) - Not a test site! Only used by staffs
- DevDays - This has been [discontinued](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/265263).
- [SO Email Host](https://email.stackoverflow.com/)
- [SO Email Host Alt](https://stackoverflow.email/)

- [The other Steve](https://clc.stackoverflow.com)

#### Other apex domains that the Stack Exchange company owns:

- [Stack Promos](https://stackpromos.com)
- [SO Business](https://www.stackoverflowbusiness.com)
- [StackAuth](https://stackauth.com) (The server that enables cross-domain login so you don't have to login separately to SO, SU, SF, AU, etc.)
- [Stack Snippets](https://stacksnippets.net)
- [Stack Overflow for Teams](https://stackoverflowteams.com/) - since the [removal](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/383092/5958455) of Teams from the main site domain and sidebar

Comment: +1 for SO Blog, I forgot to mention that, you sure there are no other subdomains left to mention ?

Comment: @GypsyCosmonaut The universe is infinite. We can never say we've finished exploration. But we can know when God (SE employee) tells us "That's all".

Comment: hahaha.. "...God (SE employee)...". True

Comment: Bro, subdomains which have some different content. Redirects would not be counted. I can also mention https://www.superuser.com and https://superuser.com are two separate domains.

Comment: The Stack Snippet domains are fraud.

Comment: @ShadowWizard Proof or reference?

Comment: See the whois data. They are held by private company which only redirects to exisitng questions on SO, some without any snippet. They make money from the Google Ads when people search there.

Comment: @ShadowWizard Good suggestion for Whois data.

Comment: Another one: https://email.stackoverflow.com/

Comment: And don't forget Steve! https://clc.stackoverflow.com/ (https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/323297/who-is-the-other-steve ;))

Comment: @ShadowWizard Lol... Forgot SO Email. I even received one :D

Comment: There's used to be a [docs-beta.stackexchange.com](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/330259/what-is-docs-beta-stackexchange-com) for Docs's private beta, but it's closed now since Docs sunsetted.

Comment: @Panda Strictly speaking, the docs-beta site was shut down when Documentation went into public beta on Stack Overflow itself, back in July 2016.

Comment: Another one: [Stack](https://stackoverflow.design), the CSS & pattern libraries for the Network
 ([details here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/313846/when-was-stack-overflow-s-css-pattern-libraries-stacks-launched))

Comment: Sci-Fi and Fantasy was originally just sci-fi, not originally just fantasy.

Comment: Plenty more redirectors if you're going to list everything including https://fantasy.stackexchange.com/ Like https://tv.stackexchange.com/ or my favourite https://thefinalfrontier.stackexchange.com/

Comment: <https://rads.stackoverflow.com/> Now throws a [site not found on SE](https://stackexchange.com/site-not-found), rather than redirecting to SO.

Comment: I know at least one other site has changed domains: https://programmers.stackexchange.com/ now redirects to https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/.

Comment: Also, https://talent.stackoverflow.com/ now redirects to https://stackoverflow.co/talent/.

Answer (score 5):

In addition to the sites mentioned by iBug, we have:

- [Area 51](https://area51.stackexchange.com/) (it's linked to at the bottom of the list, but it's not *in* the list)
- [Stack Exchange API](http://api.stackexchange.com/)
- The various Winter Bash sites:

  - [Winter Bash 2016](https://winterbash2016.stackexchange.com/)
  - Older years exist as well, but redirect to stackpromos.com
- [CS50](https://cs50.stackexchange.com/) (a Q&A site for Harvard University's CS50x course)
- We used to have elections.stackexchange.com but it's [currently down](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/294719/elections-stackexchange-com-isnt-loading).

Comment: That's all? Sure ? How can I verify this is all StackExchange has got?

Comment: I don't think Area 51 should be added. It's in the sites list in the top-left dropdown menu.

Comment: I'm not sure either, but the OP asked for subdomains which are not in the list of All Sites.

Comment: If we're doing stackoverflow.com subdomains BTW, the list continues: https://insights.stackoverflow.com, https://jobs.stackoverflow.com/ and https://careers.stackoverflow.com/ (redirects to SO Talent), https://business.stackoverflow.com/ (redirects to SO Business)

Comment: Note: https://jobs.stackoverflow.com/ and https://careers.stackoverflow.com/ now redirect to a message indicating that Stack Overflow Jobs and Developer Story were shut down, and https://business.stackoverflow.com/ now redirects to https://stackoverflow.com/?products/. (And, of course, Winter Bash 2022's site isn't up yet but 2021 and older are now archived on https://contests.stackoverflow.com/ (e.g. [2021](https://contests.stackoverflow.com/promos/22/winter-bash-2021).)