# Are there any other communities like sopython?

Tags: discussion

As I expressed my problem in [an earlier question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/299365/359533) also, all websites on Stack Exchange are not listed anywhere. You won't know they're there until you stumble upon them.

I came across the [sopython](https://sopython.com/) community today. I went ahead to this website and when I hit on login, I was logged in with my current username on Stack Exchange. So, I assume that sopython is another website of Stack Exchange dedicated to specifically Python developers. Am I correct?

Are there any other Stack Overflow communities dedicated specifically to other languages like SOhaskell, SOc (for C and C++), SOx86 (for x86)?

Comment: There's nothing mentioned on StackExchange to search for @PatrickHofman . You mean, I should rely on other websites to rely on information gathering about StackExchange and not this website? There's literally just one thread other than this mentioning anything about sopython on this website which is https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/270865/359533 .Where do you think I should clarify ?

Comment: Why do you point at me? Did I downvote you?

Comment: Why would you limit the research you do before posting a question to a single site?

Comment: @GypsyCosmonaut, if you aren't aware, [voting on Meta is a bit different than that on SE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-meta).

Answer (score 3):

> So, I assume that sopython is another website of StackExchange dedicated to specifically Python developers.

Wrong, it is a community driven project that just uses the authentication flow SE provides for apps to authenticate. It has nothing to do with SO 'the company'.

Another good example of such sites or communities is [charcoal-se.org](https://charcoal-se.org), the community-driven anti-spam crew.

Answer (score 2):

> So, I assume that sopython is another website of StackExchange dedicated to specifically Python developers. Am I correct ?

No, it's not a site run by SE.  It's a 3rd party site of users that are also active members of SE's community.

I imagine you could also find other 3rd party sites of people that identify as SE users, although I don't know of any; Google could help you try and search for some.

Comment: [Metasmoke](http://metasmoke.erwaysoftware.com/) uses the same authentication method.

Comment: @Glorfindel Sure.  Anyone in the world can use it.  That's the whole point of  OpenID.